# PHP error when loading library in Codeiginiter

Tags: php, codeigniter, class

I've included the [ColorsOfImage PHP class from humanmade](https://github.com/humanmade/Colors-Of-Image) into my Codeigniter as a new library.

Now when I load the library in a controller, I can use the functions of the class without any problems, but I always get the following error when loading the library, which says, that the `$image` in the `__construct` function is empty!?

Here is the __construct function of the class:

```
public function __construct( $image, $precision = 10, $maxnumcolors = 5, $trueper = true ) {
        $this->image = $image;
        $this->maxnumcolors = $maxnumcolors;
        $this->trueper = $trueper;
        $this->getImageSize();
        $this->precision = $precision;
        $this->readPixels();
        $this->_excluded_colors[] = $this->getBackgroundColor();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check [docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/loader.html#CI_Loader::library) where is said:

```
library($library[, $params = NULL[, $object_name = NULL]])
```

> Parameters:
>
> - $library (mixed) – Library name as a string or an array with multiple libraries
> - $params (array) – Optional array of parameters to pass to the loaded library’s constructor
> - $object_name (string) – Optional object name to assign the library to

In case of CI using custom library with constructor parameters from a controller:

```
$this->load->library('colorsofimage', [$image, $precision = 10, $maxnumcolors = 5, $trueper = true]);
```